# td value is not coming inside coolautosuggest jQuery function

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to access `td` value inside `coolautosuggest`function but its giving `undefined value`.

HTML CODE:

```
<table class="table table-bordered cust_job_over">
  <thead>
    <tr>

      <th>Skillset</th>
      <th>Assignee</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="LabourTbody">
    <tr>

      <td width="45%">
        <input type="hidden" class="labourAssetID" value="31" name=""><span class="skill">0.35m Planer Operator</span></td>
      <td width="40%" style="position: relative;">
        <input type="hidden" class="" value="167,169,172,173" name="">
        <input type="text" class="form-control cool-auto-suggest" style="width: 90% !important;float:left;">
        <div class="assig_noti assign_complete cust_job_over_noti"></div>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td width="45%">
        <input type="hidden" class="labourAssetID" value="33" name=""><span class="skill">Sweeper Driver (CE)</span></td>
      <td width="40%" style="position: relative;">
        <input type="hidden" class="" value="167,169,172,173" name="">
        <input type="text" class="form-control cool-auto-suggest" style="width: 90% !important;float:left;">
        <div class="assig_noti assign_complete cust_job_over_noti"></div>
      </td>

    </tr>


  </tbody>
</table>
```

JQUERY CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".cool-auto-suggest").coolautosuggest({
    url: window.location.origin + "/datalist/",
    showThumbnail: true,
    showDescription: true,
    additionalFields: {
      "/asset": $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0) .labourAssetID')
    },
    onSelected: function(result) {

    }
  });
});
```

This is where I'm getting undefined value  `"/asset": $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0) .labourAssetID')`

[This is the plugin](http://stuff.w3shaman.com/jquery-plugins/coolautosuggest/?text4=Angelina%20Jolie&text4_id=18)  which I'm trying to implement.

Can anyone suggest me how to get the closest `td`  input value using `class name` inside this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `$(this)` is referencing to the document object, because you're inside the context of the `$(document).ready()` event.

If you have multiple `cool-auto-suggest` classes, you need to iterate over each element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".cool-auto-suggest").each(function() {
    // Here I save reference to the current iterated object
    var $el = $(this);

    // Here I calling the plugin separately, for each '.cool-auto-suggest' 
    $el.coolautosuggest({
      url: window.location.origin + "/datalist/",
      showThumbnail: true,
      showDescription: true,
      additionalFields: {
        // Here I select the correct element using the reference ($el)
        "/asset": $el.closest('tr').find('td:eq(0) .labourAssetID') 
      },
      onSelected: function(result) {

      }
    });
  });
});
```